# Understanding Single Responsibility Pattern (SRP)

Tags: ruby, single-responsibility

According to the Single Responsibility Pattern (SRP) a method or class should have one responsibility. I have read a couple of sources and viewed some videos and I would like to understand it by writing some code samples.

According to me, the following:

```
def addAndSubtract(a,b,c)
  a + b - c
end
```

is conflicting with the SRP as this method has two responsibilities, i.e. addition and subtraction.

So how to align this with SRP? One responsibility per method right? Is the following correct?

```
def addAndSubtractSrp(a,b,c)
  subtract(add(a,b),c)
end

def add(a,b)
  a + b
end

def subtract(a,b)
  a - b
end
```

**Discussion**

According to me, this is aligned with SRP as there are now two methods that have one responsibility. When I would like to add multiplication and division then I need to create separate methods right?

Comment: I agree this is a dupe. Also, single responsibility could be a function ,(method) that calculates a complex algorithm. The point of SRP isn't to do a single operation, it's to manage change as the codebase evolves.

Comment: 1. SRP is a *class* principle.  It has no meaning for methods.  Methods have a different metric: *only do one thing.*  Yours does two things.

Comment: 2.  `According to me, this is aligned with SRP as there are now two methods that have one responsibility.` -- No.  `addAndSubtractSrp`  still does two things; it adds and subtracts.  That you've refactored out the equation (and turned it into two methods, making the whole thing more complicated) doesn't change that fact.

Comment: 3.  To fix your method so that it only does one thing, change its name to something like `adjustBalance`, or whatever that equation actually accomplishes.

Comment: At this point you should have asked yourself: Is the single responsibility principle total nonsense and something that should be avoided, or am I understanding it wrong? Because your code change is total nonsense.